# JSON.parse - SyntaxError: Unexpected token & at Object.parse (native)

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8

I'm trying to parse the following string to JSON and it does not seem to work due to the ampersand character `\&\#38`. It throws an error on JSON.parse: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token & at Object.parse (native)`

`{"pluginType":"cite","reference":{"title":"Mixed-Initiative Real-Time Topic Modeling \&\#38; Visualization for Crisis Counseling","url":"http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2678025.2701395","pages":"417--426","year":"2015","publisher":"ACM","_id":"56d59ced7eb2323d008fab24","label":"Dinakar2015MRT26780252701395"}}`

Can this be escaped somehow? It seems like valid input for a user.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"pluginType":"cite","reference":{"title":"Mixed-Initiative Real-Time Topic Modeling \&\#38; Visualization for Crisis Counseling","url":"http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2678025.2701395","pages":"417--426","year":"2015","publisher":"ACM","_id":"56d59ced7eb2323d008fab24","label":"Dinakar2015MRT26780252701395"}}')` parses fine for me.

Comment: @thomas That's because JS converts the literal `'\&'` into the string `&`. Try `JSON.parse(String.raw\`"\&"\`)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An escaping `\` can't precede `&`.

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>

If you wanted to escape `&`, just use `&` (there is no need to escape it).

```js
document.write(JSON.parse(String.raw`"&"`));
```

If you wanted the string `\&`, you need to escape the `\` like `\\&`.

```js
document.write(JSON.parse(String.raw`"\\&"`));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is semi-automatically generated so I can't really prevent that from being inputted, but I want to not crash on it. Is there a javascript function that will escape characters like that properly? What are the other characters except `&` that I would need to escape?

Comment: You **must not** escape `&` in JSON. Clarify if you wanted `&` or `\&`.